# Conjugate Puiseux expansions in Mathematica

Tags: series-expansion, diophantine-equations

In a paper "A quantitative version of Runge’s theorem on diophantine equations" ACTA ARITHMETICA
LXII.2 (1992), P. G. Walsh developed a method to solve all 2-variable diophantine equations for which the following condition does not hold

(C4) the algebraic function $y = y(x)$ defined by $F(x, y) = 0$ has only one class of conjugate Puiseux expansions.

The question is: how to verify in Mathematica whether a given polynomial $F(x,y)$ with integer coefficients satisfy this condition? For example, let $F(x,y)=y^3 + x y + x^4 + 4$.

If I use

```
AsymptoticSolve[y^3 + x y + x^4 + 4 == 0, y, {x, 0, 3}]
```

in Mathematica12, I get

```
{{y -> -(-2)^(2/3) - ((-1)^(1/3) x)/(3 2^(2/3)) - ((-1)^(2/3) x^3)/(
    648 2^(1/3))}, {y -> -2^(2/3) + x/(3 2^(2/3)) - x^3/(
    648 2^(1/3))}, {y -> (-1)^(1/3) 2^(2/3) + 1/3 (-(1/2))^(2/3) x + 
    1/648 (-(1/2))^(1/3) x^3}}
```

So, 3 expansions in total. How to check whether they are all conjugate? Maple code https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=algcurves/puiseux seems to compute Puiseux expansions up to conjugacy, so I would just see if it returns one expansion or more, but I do not have access to Maple.

Also, does it matter what initial point to choose? In (C4), no point is mentioned, but AsymptoticSolve is Mathematica require an initial point.